# Change the Values of the app config file in a windows service through another program

Tags: windows-services, app-config

I have a windows service which downloads some files from SFTP and uploads it to database and generates PDf's from that data. So now when i should give the executable files to my client i think he need to change the app config file like sftp details and the pdf paths. So i am just thinking about a program like a windows forms or a console which reads the input and save those in app config file. Is it possible like and by the way i have created a setup project for the windows service where he gets 2 files .msi file and setup file. Is it possible to achieve the above problem in this case ?

Comment: This is possible. You can use [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) to open the other project'

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're wanting some kind of UI application that allows the user to configure the operation of the Windows service.  This is certainly possible as I've been doing it for several years now.  However, you **don't** want to do this via the app.config file.  The app.config file is read by the Windows service when it starts up, so any changes made to it would go unnoticed until the service restarts.  A better course of action would be to communicate the changes to the service via the [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx) (or some other ICP mechanism, e.g., pipes, sockets, shared memory, etc.).  I've managed to use this successfully, although to be honest, I'm using ordinary sockets now.  In any case, the service would basically "listen" for incoming configuration messages, "read" those messages, and then "configure" itself accordingly, perhaps even saving the changes in its app.config file so the changes are preserved for when the service restarts later.

HTH